# Is it possible to make a pattern for a CGContext Path using a png

Tags: iphone, path, png, design-patterns, cgcontext

I want to make a path that has a png as it's pattern, or if you could or think it would be easier to make my own pattern, then tell me that also. I will be greatful to anyone who can put up some code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly. Are you trying to fill or stroke the path with the pattern? I guess the way to go is:

1. Create the path you want to fill or stroke.
2. Create a pattern with `CGPatternCreate()`. This function takes a lot of parameters, among them a pointer to a drawing callback function that will be called whenever the pattern is used. So you would place your code to draw the PNG image in this function. Create a `CGImage` and use `CGContextDrawImage()` to draw it into the graphics context provided by the callback function.
3. Call `CGContextSetFillColorSpace()` or `CGContextSetStrokeColorSpace()` with `CGColorSpaceCreatePattern()` to set a pattern color space (necessary for the next step).
4. Call `CGContextSetFillPattern()` or `CGContextSetStrokePattern()` to tell Quartz to use your pattern for filling/stroking.
5. Call `CGContextDrawPath()` to draw the path.

Refer to the docs for more info on all these functions.

Comment: Ok sorry, what I meant by the question was that i want to stroke the path with a pattern that looks like chalk, now I just don't know how to use CGPatternCreate to make a pattern containing a .png. I hope that answers your inquiry.